# C++ Final or Sealed

Tags: c++, final, sealed

Consider the following class:

```
class X {
};
```

One can easily inherit from this:

```
class Y : public X {
};
```

Okay so far... Let's say we don't want anyone to inherit from `Y` we can then do this instead.

```
class Y sealed : public X {
};
```

Or we could do this:

```
class Y final : public X 
};
```

What are the main differences between the two keywords `final` and `sealed`? I know their basic purposes and what they are used for; I just wanted to know if there was anything specifically different between the two.

Comment: `sealed` is not standard C++.

Comment: Microsoft doing Microsoft things....

Comment: I wasn't 100% sure; thank you for the response

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate as I was asking the difference between the two and not so much if one is standard and one isn't; but it's all good.

Comment: So, is it safe to say that if I have some `native` code that uses the MS specific keyword `sealed` and I want to make that code more portable I could then change `sealed` and replace it directly with `final` and that should do the job?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sealed` is not Standard C++ - it appears to be a [Visual C++ CX extension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w2w91tf.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). From that same page:

> The ISO C++11 Standard language has the `final` keyword, which is supported in Visual Studio. Use `final` on standard classes, and `sealed` on ref classes.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Now I know that `final` is through the standard and `sealed` is MS specific, otherwise they do basically the same thing.